# Bound on maximum of random variable by moments.

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

I am looking at the following paper and the following is eluding me:

Source: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdfview_1/euclid.aos/1387313390, B.4. Proof of Corollary 2.1.

Rephrasing of the question: Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be independent random variables with $E[X_i]=0$ for all $i$. Let $B=\underbrace{\max}_{1\leq i\leq n} \sqrt{E[X_i^2]}$. Suppose there are constants $c_1,C_1>0$, such that $c_1\leq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i^2]\leq C_1$. Let constant $B_n>0$ be such that
$$\max_{k=1,2}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E\left[\frac{|X_i|^{2+k}}{B^k_n}\right]+E\left[e^{|X_i|/B_n}\right]\leq 4.$$
Prove that there exists a $C$ depending on $c_1,C_1$ such that
$$B\leq CB_n.$$

According to the paper this should be an elementary application of Holder's Inequality, but I find it difficult to not include $n$ in $C$.

Note: I realise that $E\left[e^{|X_i|/B_n}\right]\leq 4$ might be sufficient, if we take $4\geq \max E\left[e^{|X_i|/B_n}\right]\geq \max E[(|X_i|/B_n)^2/2]$ (by Taylor expansion) $=\frac{B^2}{2B_n^2}?$ I am still curious if there may be a way by Holder's.

Comment: $B_n$ is constrained to be non-negative, I assume?

Comment: Yes that is right.

Comment: @61plus you're saying $C$ is absolute and doesn't depend on $c_1,C_1$?

Comment: $C$ will depend on $c_1,C_1$.

Comment: @61plus (you should tag me so I get a notification) didn't you prove that $4 \ge \frac{B^2}{2B_n^2}$? That gives $C = 2\sqrt{2}$, which is absolute.

Comment: @mathworker21 I see what you mean. Looking at the paper, they were using $C$ to bound other quantities too which led to $c_1,C_1$ being needed.

Comment: But you are right that in this case an absolute constant is sufficient.

Comment: @61plus Where are you getting $4 \ge \max E[e^{|X_i|/B_n}]$ from? I don't understand how you got $4 \ge \frac{B^2}{2B_n^2}$.

Comment: @mathworker21 The inequality $\max_{k=1,2}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n E\left[\frac{|X_i|^{2+k}}{B^k_n}\right]+E\left[e^{|X_i|/B_n}\right]\leq 4$ is true for all $i$.

Comment: @61plus huh? ur summing over $i$

Comment: @mathworker21 The expression might look a little strange but the summation is only for the first term.